# VIM plugin for autocomplete for "from import" combination

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I observed that Atom editor has one very good functionality, which is when I type while working with python

```
from XXX import
```

it shows list of items that can be imported from XXX

Atom shows a list of things that can be imported. Can VIM also be configured for the same ?

Is there any plugin ?

Answer (score 3):

[image: import completion]

Vim has four features that can be used to complete imports in Python:

- `:help 'include'` tells Vim how to recognize an "include" in your code. The default value for Python (`^\s*\(from\|import\)`) is reasonable.
- `:help 'define'` can be used to tell Vim how a definition is supposed to look. There's no Python-specific default value but the following would be a good start:

  ```
  :set define=^\\s*def
  ```
- `:help compl-define` lets you complete from the definitions gathered in included files with `<C-x><C-d>`. Or you could customize `:help 'complete'` to include definitions and simply use `<C-p>` or `<C-n>`:

  ```
  :set complete+=d
  ```
- `:help 'path'` tells Vim where to look for files when you do `:find` or `gf` or include/define completion. For it to be of any use, though, `'path'` must be set carefully.

Everything is here and relatively easy to set up, but there certainly are Python plugins that do all that for you in a smarter way.

Comment: How you are getting that in the screen shot ? This is the way atom is showing though without path just name

Comment: also why is it showing popitem which is not a part of os ?

Comment: First question: I pressed `<C-x><C-d>` in insert mode. Second question: because it is not really smart.

Comment: how is atom doing it in a smart way ?

Comment: How Atom does it I have no idea. Maybe it bundles some python code that uses introspection to know what to suggest when. That's what Jedi does, AFAIK.

Comment: I am on MacOSX and the combination you mentioned is not working. Are you also on Mac ?

Comment: Yes I'm on a Mac, obviously. You have to add the path to the python headers to Vim's `'path'` option. For me it's `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried 

set path=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 

in .vimrc but after that also it didn't work

Comment: The important part of "For me it's…" is "For me". You will have to figure out where your headers are. You can try `>>> import sys` and then `>>> print sys.path` in the Python REPL.

Comment: Or in Vim: `:py import sys` and `:py print sys.path`.

Comment: I have upvoted your solution but honestly this is not what I want

Comment: It's exactly what you ask, though.

Comment: I've replaced the static screenshot with a gif. Starting point is an almost stock Vim.

Comment: If you see Atom functionality you would realise. You don't even have to type even partially after from XX import. It automatically lists all possible imports from the XX package so that you can choose

Comment: All I show is built-in functionality and Vim (thankfully) doesn't have autocompletion. If you want autocompletion, use an autocompletion plugin, as per the other answer.

Comment: I am using YouCompleteMe but it doesn't have this functionality

Answer (score 3):

It turns out what I was looking for is CTRL+Space

In Atom this part is automated as in you don't even have to press CTRL+Space

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot. But these are the current best:

1. Deoplete + deoplete-jedi

   1. https://github.com/zchee/deoplete-jedi
   2. https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim
2. Using LSP

   1. https://github.com/neovim/python-client
   2. https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim

Comment: Isn't nvim for NeoVim ? My requirement is for VIM